# Powershell CSV foreach loop

Tags: powershell, csv

I had a look at other questions and couldn't find one which helped me with my particular issue, apologies

I have 100+ items in a CSV and I want to put each into two sections of a command. I want this to then be looped through using the following:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\name\test.csv"       
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    {

       $export = Get-DistributionGroupMember "$user" | Select-Object Identity,Alias,City,Company  | Export-Csv "$user.csv" 
    }
}
```

What am i looking over?

edit

[image: This is the current output] this is the current output, i'm hoping that the $user would be replaced by each line in the CSV

Comment: Where are you defining/setting values for `$csv` and `$title`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - i've updated the code, apologies had copied one I was playing around with

Comment: There's no need for the double `{{  }}` only one pair is needed with `foreach`. So what exactly is your problem/question, "looking over" doesn't mean much?

Comment: What results are you getting, and what results do you _expect_ to get?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Apologies again, added

Comment: Where is `Get-DistributionGroupMember` defined? What does it do?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it's part of the MS Exchange module

Comment: @JamesC. - Thanks; I don't have access to that module; I'm in a large organization and managing Exchange isn't part of my responsibilities.

Comment: For one thing: remove the nested scriptblock. What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Step 1: Remove the extra `{}` as per James C.'s and Ansgar Wiechers's comments. It _shouldn't_ make a difference, but...   Step 2: Make sure you don't have any extraneous quotation marks lying around, and that you've closed every quotation mark you've opened - there's no reason that I can see that it should be emitting the line of code - unless there's an extraneous or unclosed quote.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers @James C - I've removed the nested {} - this actually seemed to be the main issue, however, the new issue` "The operation couldn't be performed because object '@{LINE1=LINE2}' couldn't be found on '.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'."`

Comment: You're importing a CSV, so the value of `$Users` is a list of custom objects with properties named after the headers of the CSV. Expand the property with the usernames to get a list with just the usernames: `$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Securus\test.csv" | Select-Object -Expand WhateverTheNameOfYourUsernameFieldMightBe`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you're bang on, I had removed "alias" which was causing the double line, adding this back and running it appears to run correctly - I now need work identify exactly why it's adding "@{Alias=<text>} when i still only want <text>

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the issue was not using $user.Alias and only using $user - issue now fixed and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the double `{{ }}` you have with the `foreach`:

Here's a quick demo to show what it's doing:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 1..3 | foreach {Write-Host $_}
1
2
3

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 1..3 | foreach {{Write-Host $_}}
Write-Host $_
Write-Host $_
Write-Host $_
```

Comment: Hmmm... I guess that it _does_ make a difference; I wonder why? I'd gotten the impression that `{}` was like the same in C/C++/C#, or like `BEGIN...END` in Pascal.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The nested curly brackets define a scriptblock (basically an anonymous function), which doesn't magically invoke itself. What's a bit confusing about PowerShell is that in some cases the curly brackets define begin/end of a nested context (e.g. in `foreach` loops or `try..catch` statements) while in other cases they define scriptblocks that are passed as arguments (e.g. with `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object`).

Comment: @James C - I've done all changes suggested and now seem to have a working script my main issue is that instead of just using the text in the CSV it's adding "@{alias=<text>}" instead of just <text> - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The exact code which resolved the issue:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\name\test.csv"       
foreach ($user in $users)
{ 

       $export = Get-DistributionGroupMember $user.Alias | Select-Object Identity,Alias,City,Company  | Export-Csv "$User.csv"
}
```

Thanks